# What is post*treat value in the year of event?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

Regarding **Difference-in-Difference**, from this paper of [Dasgupta,2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/32/7/2587/5079300?redirectedFrom=fulltext), I am wondering if they use the data of the observations on the event year.

I asked this question because in their paper, they did not mention clearly whether they use the data on event year in their study.
What they said from section 3.1 is

> Figure 1 plots the mean of the mean change in asset growth of treated
> firms and control firms in the same industry, 2 years before and 5
> years after the adoption of a leniency law in a country. Thus, the
> control firms are all firms in the same industry in countries that had
> not passed a leniency law in the 7 years **surrounding** the event date.

I am wondering why they say "7 years surrounding the event"? Whether "**surrounding the event date**" *includes the event date*?

For clarifying the question, for example:

If Korea passed the law in 1997, so the treatment including Korean firms in 1995,1996,**1997**,1998,1999,2000,2001 and the Korean firms in 1997,1998,1999,2000,2001 will receive the value of 1 (**post x treatment**)

or

the treatment including Korean firms in 1995,1996,1998,1999,2000,2001,**2002** and the Korean firms in 1998,1999,2000,2001,2002 will receive the value of 1 (**post x treatment**)

or another option as one answer below

> So, Treat x Post of Korean firms in 1995,1996 will receive the values
> of 0 but Korean firms in 1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002 will receive
> the value of 1. That is why I said 8 years in total. "7 years
> surrounding" here means 2 years before and 5 years after and the event
> year, totally 8 years.

Answer (score 0):

First, clarifying the definition of "treatment" and "post":

1. **Treatment** is the units that were treated, independent of time.
2. **Post** is the year **when treatment began**.
3. **Treat x Post** : is your effect and includes treated firms in treated years.
   Let's say t=0 is the year of the event and t>0 are posterior years.

So the **treatment** includes only treated firms in all years. **Post** includes all firms only in treated years when **t>=0**. So, in your case, it would be the first case

> If Korea passed the law in 1997, so the treatment including Korean
> firms in 1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001 and the Korean firms in
> 1997,1998,1999,2000,2001 will receive the value of 1 (post x
> treatment)

But I also learnt something from this paper. It seems that, he used 8 years for a treatment in total. Let's say, if Korea passed the law in 1997.
So, **Treat x Post** of Korean firms in **1995,1996** will receive the values of 0 but Korean firms in **1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002** will receive the value of 1. That is why I said ***8 years*** in total.
"7 years surrounding" here means 2 years before and 5 years after and the event year, totally 8 years.

But it is still ambiguous to me if it is the case (**8 years**)

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, but it seems that we are still ambiguous about it is 7 or 8 years in total for a treatment country.

Comment: The post-treatment variable isn't well-defined in this setting. You don't need to define it. The binary treatment variable (i.e., $LL_{kt}$) should just 'turn on' if a country is in the treatment group *and* is in a post-treatment time period. The interaction term is implicit in the coding of the treatment dummy. Assuming the law is passed in 1997, then the dummy for Korean firms should equal 1 in 1997 and stay on for the duration of the panel.

Comment: By "7 years surrounding the event" they mean the effects in the 2 years before and the 5 years after the event date. The periods are "relative to" the first adoption year.

Comment: Many thanks for your clarification, Thomas. I want to clarify one more thing:  if I understand you correctly, if Korea passed the laws in 1997, so 1995 and 1996 is pre-period and the binary treatment variable being turned on in 6 years: 1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,**2002**