# Is it wrong when ignoring the event year in generalized Difference-in-Difference?

Tags: difference-in-difference

In a generalized Difference in Difference for staggered year event, from [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526244/what-is-posttreat-value-in-the-year-of-event), we need to include the event year to the sample.

For example, if Korea passed the law in 1997, so **post*treat** should receive the value of 0 for 1995 and 1996 while it receives the value of 1 for **1997**,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002.

I am wondering if I can exclude the year 1997 in this case out of my sample, is there any justification for this exclusion. I mean, **post*treat** equals to 0 for 1995 and 1996 while it receives value of 1 for 1998,1999,2000,2001,2002.

If this exclusion is wrong, so I am wondering why it is wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude 1997?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I just asked of my curiousity, Thomas. Because I want to know "what if" to make sure I understand the setting thoroughly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the model is fully saturated with treatment indicators to show the full dynamic response to treatment, then I see no justifiable reason to exclude a period, let alone excluding the immediate adoption year. And even when we do include a full series of lead/lag indicators, we typically exclude a *pre-treatment* year. You could drop the year before treatment, or a more distant period. However, excluding the initial adoption year is very rare in practice.

I suppose if you suspect effects kick in with a one year lag, then excluding the year of adoption seems warranted, but again it's rare. Maybe it took a long time for treated firms in Korea to adapt to the new law/policy. Even then, I wouldn't recommend excluding a period unless the model was saturated. If only a finite number of pre-treatment "leads" were considered (i.e., 2 leads), then all the years *before* 1995 may serve as a reference.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. However, regarding "And even when we do include a full series of lead/lag indicators, we typically exclude a *pre-treatment* year", is there any reference or justification for this statement then?

Comment: Apart from that, you said "If only a finite number of pre-treatment "leads" were considered (i.e., 2 leads), then all the years *before* 1995 may serve as a reference". Can I ask what does this sentence mean, especially the word **reference** in this case.

Comment: The justification is that we need a reference period. In most impact evaluations the authors typically drop the period immediately before treatment. You could use a more distant period but this is not as common, at least in the literature I've encountered on this topic.

Comment: And by "reference" I mean the *pre-treatment* epoch. In a typical event study framework evaluators may assess effects in all periods before *and* after treatment. In essence, we're assessing the evolution of effects *in reference to* the omitted period.

Comment: A very clear and thorough explanation, just the last question. So "we're assessing the evolution of effects in reference to the omitted period", so the **reference** here mean **pre-treatment period** and **omitted period** is **post-treatment period**?

Comment: The period we omit is our reference period. In applied work, evaluators typically drop a pre-treatment period. The period you omit is up to you, but the period immediately *before* treatment starts is a popular choice. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes totally sense now, thank you so much

Comment: @ThomasBilach I am interested in this discussion. I am wondering if you mean your reference period is the pre-treatment period and omitted period is the time you end your pre-treatment period? For example of OP, Korea passed the laws in 1997, so the reference period is 1995->1996, and 1996 is omitted period?

Comment: I need more information to answer this question. Are we only considering a finite number of leads and lags? It depends on the context.